# Name of degenerate parameter dependent ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, bifurcation

I am looking for literature on specific type of degeneracy for odes.

Consider the phase space $M= \{ (x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \}$ and the ode of the general form:
\begin{align}
\alpha \frac{d x_1}{dt} &= f_1(x_1,x_2) \\
\frac{d x_2}{dt} &= f_2(x_1,x_2) \\
\end{align}
with $f_1,f_2$ Lipschitz and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ a parameter. I am interested in the $\alpha$-dependence of the solutions $(x_1,x_2)$. Specifically, in what happens to the solutions  in the limit $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ where the ode becomes 1-dimensional (For example, does this happen uniformly?).

I am sure that these odes have been studied before. However, I am not able to find what they are called.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small $\alpha$, the system is called *singularly perturbed*. The solutions to singularly perturbed dynamical systems are studied using *multiple time scale analysis* and/or *geometric singular perturbation theory*. For more information on this subject, and especially the relation between the system when $\alpha$ is small but nonzero, and when $\alpha$ is identically zero, I highly recommend

C. Kuehn, *Multiple Time Scale Dynamics*, Springer, 2015.